# Swift, Change UIButton color, by tag value

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, button, colors

Im trying to change a UIButtons color, using tag value, I have 2 different codes, but none of them works.

```
self.view.viewWithTag(Int(buttonNumber))?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()




var tempButton = self.view.viewWithTag(Int(buttonNumber)) as? UIButton

tempButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

None of theese works, and i can't find out how to solve this

Comment: self.view.viewWithTag(Int(buttonNumber)) returns nil of course

Comment: how many buttons you have ?

Comment: and of course Int(buttonNumber), is the tag number :)

Comment: Can you post your view hierarchy ? Are your buttons added directly to the main view ? How are you setting buttons tag?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var tempButton = self.view.viewWithTag(Int(buttonNumber)) as? UIButton
tempButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
```

I hope it helps